# Call `show` on Marionette LayoutView region

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have this Layout View:

```
var appLayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: function() {
        return "some template string";
    },
    regions: {
        notify: "[data-region='Notify']"
    },
    onShow: function() {
        this.regions.notify.show(new notifyView());
    }
});
```

Which I call like so:

```
mainLayout.app.show(appLayout);
```

So ideally, I'd like, when I run the above line (essentially when the layout view is put into the DOM) for the `notifyView` to be rendered into the "notify" region. However `this.regions.notify` is just a string. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do here? Basically having the render logic for "notify" inside the Layout View class, and not controlled from the invocation line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any docs that show where this got added, but `LayoutView` should have a `getRegion` method : 
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.layoutview.js#L74

so your code would look like :

```
var appLayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: function() {
        return "some template string";
    },
    regions: {
        notify: "[data-region='Notify']"
    },
    onShow: function() {
        this.getRegion('notify').show(new notifyView());
    }
});
```

Comment: Awhhhhh yiss! Will give that a go